# UIPickerView as an inputView of multiple UITextFields

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitextfield, uipickerview

I have three [UITextField](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield)s in my code and single [UIPickerView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerview) as in [inputView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield/1619620-inputview) of all text fields.

I want to identify, which text field has invoked/opened UIPickerView, inside the [UIPickerViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerviewdelegate) method [pickerView(_:didSelectRow:inComponent:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerviewdelegate/1614371-pickerview).

Here is sample code I've tried:

```
let tf1: UITextField()
let tf2: UITextField()
let tf3: UITextField()
let pcv: UIPickerView()


tf1.inputView = pcv
tf2.inputView = pcv
tf3.inputView = pcv


// Picker view delegate
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if (tf1.isFirstResponder) {
       print("tf1")
    } else if (tf2.isFirstResponder) {
       print("tf2")
    } else if (tf3.isFirstResponder) {
       print("tf3")
    } else {
       print("Any other view")
    }

}
```

Is there any other better way to handle this?

(Objective C or Swift, any solution)

Comment: I know you want to do that inside pickerview delegate but, if you are open to other things, you could get it on `textFieldDidBeginEditing` for `UITextFieldDelegate`

Comment: @DanielAmarante - Could you please guide me. how?

Comment: You can check with tf1.inputView != nil

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that. What is happening with the isFirstResponder?

Comment: Why do you think it's not a better way to handle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on your textfield delegate assign the inputview and tag for your textfield

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
   textField.inputView = pcv
   pcv.tag =  textField.tag
    return true;
}
```

and finally get the tag for pickerview for identify which textfield you tapped.

```
 func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        print("pickerView == \(pickerView.tag)")

}
```

Comment: correct answer..! But my bad - I've used [IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager/issues/88)

Comment: @Krunal - okay you need to disable the func for single viewcontroller. else you need to override the IQKeyboard manager delegates for one viewcontroller

Comment: Yes, you are right, I can. But then I will have to handle textfield (position) manually.

Comment: @Krunal - check this link once: https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager/issues/473